# Como tornar o Git sensível à caixa?

Tags: git, sensibilidade-de-caixa

O meu sistema operacional é não é sensível à caixa por padrão, o que significa que não há diferença entre a capitalização das letras de um nome de arquivo, por exemplo.

Esse comportamento me atrapalha constantemente quando estou em um repositório local Git, principalmente quando quero mudar um nome de arquivos e só altero a caixa de algumas letras do nome do arquivo. O Git nem sequer chega a reconhecer a mudança.

A pergunta é: há como mudar esse comportamento do Git, tornando-o *case sensitive* (**sensível à caixa**)?

Se sim, gostaria de saber como posso fazê-lo a **nível global** (para qualquer repositório do meu computador) e a **nível de um projeto (repositório) específico**, para que outras pessoas que eventualmente forem trabalhar nesse projeto também tenham esse tipo de pré-configuração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe a configuração `core.ignorecase`

Você pode usa-la da seguinte forma:

```
git config --global core.ignorecase [false|true]
```

É possível checar mais na [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase)