# Não consigo deletar a pasta "clonada" com Case-Sensitive no meu repositório do GitHub

Tags: github, diretório, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Eu criei um [repositório](https://github.com/JeanExtreme002/FlightRadarAPI) no Github e enviei minha aplicação contendo uma pasta X com o nome todo em minúsculo, quando na verdade, a primeira letra do nome deveria estar maiúscula.

Para resolver esse problema, eu executei o seguinte comando:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

Eu consegui alterar o nome da pasta e dei `push` para o repositório. O problema é que no GitHub, a pasta com o nome em minúsculo continua lá, junto com a pasta em maiúsculo. Exemplo:

```
folder/
Folder/
file.txt
```

Quando eu dou um `pull` ou `clone` para remover a pasta em minúsculo, o Git gera o seguinte aviso:

```
warning: the following paths have collided (e.g. case-sensitive paths
on a case-insensitive filesystem) and only one from the same
colliding group is in the working tree:
```

E quando eu abro o diretório da minha aplicação, com os arquivos e pastas puxados do GitHub, aqui no computador, só aparece a pasta com o nome em maiúsculo, me impossibilitando de apagar a pasta com o nome minúsculo.

```
Folder/
file.txt
```

O que eu faço para apagar a pasta com o nome antigo?

Comment: Relacionada: [Como tornar o Git sensível à caixa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/409961/como-tornar-o-git-sens%c3%advel-%c3%a0-caixa)

Comment: O problema ocorre por conta do fato de que, por padrão, o Git não é sensível à caixa. Uma vez que a sensibilidade seja ativada (conforme você mesmo colocou no início da pergunta), o problema não ocorreria em primeiro lugar. Claro que isso não resolve o problema que já ocorreu, mas se o Git sempre fosse sensível à caixa não aconteceria, de modo que serve como "prevenção" para futuros problemas similares. Por isso coloquei o comentário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode ter acesso às duas pastas no mesmo diretório devido o seu sistema operacional, que não diferencia arquivos e diretórios de mesmo nome com letras minúsculas ou maiúsculas.

Uma rápida solução para esse problema é renomear o diretório antigo para um outro nome, como `tmp`, utilizando o comando `git mv <old_name> <new_name>`. Depois disso, renomeie novamente a mesma pasta para o nome da sua pasta atual.

Dessa forma, o Git irá mesclar a pasta antiga com a pasta atual e irá apagar o diretório antigo, deixando apenas o atual. Seguindo o seu exemplo, tente executar os códigos abaixo:

```
$ git mv folder tmp
$ git mv tmp Folder
$ git status
```